# Call api every 20s - error "Maximum Execution Time'

Tags: php, laravel, api, cron

I want to call an api every ~20s in an Laravel app.

I created a loop with a final sleep of 20s in job that I launch with the command dispatchAfterResponse but I still get the error "Maximum Execution Time" after a while.

We can't use cron job since the minimum period is 1mn. Any idea?

Comment: There could easily be a better way - but maybe mix the two and do a 20s sleep 3 times and call it from the cron every minute?

Comment: @BrianThompson That should work, ie avoid the "Max Execution Time" error, but when I discovered "dispatchAfterResponse" I thought I can also avoid this error (like a cli script) and I wonder if there is any Laravel cde than can do this directly?

Comment: No. Laravel's scheduler is based off cron, which has a minimum of 1 minute

Comment: @aynber See my answer and I knew that Laravel is bases off cron, it's written in my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution, there is a nice package from spatie available on github.

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-cronless-schedule

https://laravel-news.com/sub-minute-and-cron-less-scheduled-tasks-in-laravel

Answer (score 0):

I Think This Must Be Done on the client side (JS) as PHP runs on the server.
you should try calling the API Through ajax requests and use the `setInterval()` function

Comment: It's server to server

Comment: @Dri372 This must be done on the client side. because if you do it on the PHP side, it wont really work and cause issues. the final option is XMLHttpReqests (AJAX).

Comment: Have you see my previous comment and answer. Don't forget, no client without server ... servers can run every 20s without pb :-)